# SQL Server get two days difference and days count from date range

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2010.

I have a table in the database with records as shown below :

```
Id | EmpName  | JoinDate                | ResignedDate
---+----------+-------------------------+--------------    
1  | Govind   | 2014-04-02 00:00:00.000 | 2014-04-02
2  | Aravind  | 2014-04-05 00:00:00.000 | 2014-04-05
3  | Aravind  | 2014-04-07 00:00:00.000 | 2014-04-10
4  | Aravind  | 2014-04-10 00:00:00.000 | 2014-04-11
5  | Aravind  | 2014-04-14 00:00:00.000 | 2014-04-16
```

Now, I want display the difference of two dates (joinDate , ResignDate) and of that date different how many count available

Sample output:

```
DateDifferent      Count
-------------      -----
0                     2
1                     1
2                     1
3                     1
```

Here am showing my sample query,

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(day, e.joinedDate , e.resignedDate), 
  COUNT(DATEDIFF(day, e.joinedDate , e.resignedDate)))
FROM 
  Employee e 
GROUP BY 
  DATEDIFF(e.joinedDate , e.resignedDate) ORDER BY (DATEDIFF(e.joinedDate , e.resignedDate)));
```

This queries is work well for mssql query browser but when I using the query in JPA Native Query (Java code) this query is not working

Any one help me ...

Comment: This is not a `java` question. Tag with `sql` and `sql-server` instead.

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by *in JPA code this query is not working*. Is it giving an error or incorrect results or no results at all?

Comment: Add code of your JPA and also where you get the error (if any)

Comment: The query you have here does not work. You are missing the first parameter in the datediff function in the group by clause and the order by clause. You have it correct in the count function so my guess is you are using a fault version of the query in your java code that you have posted here and you had a correct version of the query when you tested in SSMS.

Comment: SELECT  DATEDIFF(day,JoinDate,ResignedDate), count(DATEDIFF(day,JoinDate,ResignedDate)) AS DateDifferent FROM Employee
    GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,JoinDate,ResignedDate) 

try this one

Comment: Hi kausik i used this query in MSSQL query browser its working fine .. but when i using this query in jdbc using java this query is giving wrong count and date different

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66a02e/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
    ([Id] int, [EmpName] varchar(7), [JoinDate] datetime, [ResignedDate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Employee
    ([Id], [EmpName], [JoinDate], [ResignedDate])
VALUES
    (1, 'Govind', '2014-04-02 00:00:00', '2014-04-02 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'Aravind', '2014-04-05 00:00:00', '2014-04-05 00:00:00'),
    (3, 'Aravind', '2014-04-07 00:00:00', '2014-04-10 00:00:00'),
    (4, 'Aravind', '2014-04-10 00:00:00', '2014-04-11 00:00:00'),
    (5, 'Aravind', '2014-04-14 00:00:00', '2014-04-16 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      DATEDIFF(DAY, JoinDate, ResignedDate) AS DateDifferent
    , COUNT(DATEDIFF(DAY, JoinDate, ResignedDate)) as FrequencyOf
FROM Employee
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, JoinDate, ResignedDate)
ORDER BY DateDifferent
```

Note! You may use column aliases (e.g. DateDifferent) in the ORDER BY clause

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66a02e/3/0)**:

```
| DateDifferent | FrequencyOf |
|---------------|-------------|
|             0 |           2 |
|             1 |           1 |
|             2 |           1 |
|             3 |           1 |
```

Comment: thanks ...  This query is working well for MSSQL query browser but when i using this query in java code using jdbc its not working.. can you help me

Comment: Are you injecting parameter values? The query is very standard SQL syntax, in fact it is extremely standard stuff. I'm unable to offer an assist on the java side.